# Capture lettering from cylindrical object and generate SVG for laser engraving

Tags: 3d, modeling, laser, panorama

I've got an cylindrical object that has already been laser engraved. And I've got an identical object, with sticker instead of engraving. I want to capture the lettering, generate a SVG file and laser non-engraved objects by a professional. They can engrave round objects, but need the corresponding SVG.

The surface is evenly cylindrical, therefore no distortion in height towards the lens/transferring surface. I already tried photogrammetry, tracing using thin paper + scanning and panaroma-mode (phone). These methods have too much error in perspective, line-precision and sharpness..

My next idea was to use a motor to evenly turn it (like a "kebab machine" or lathe) and capture a video. But how to post-process it?

Comment: I suppose that the stickers do not have the lettering... You could peal some and scan them in a flat bed scanner.

Comment: @Rafael thanks, but these are different to the ones with engraved lettering and not acceptable :)

Comment: Wrap some paper around the object, use a crayon or the side of a pencil to obtain a rubbing, then scan the result, load it into a vector editor and recreate the outlines with Bezier curves.

Comment: @r3mainer tried parchment paper + pencil: https://i.imgur.com/fIx2dHL.jpg Does crayon really work better?

Comment: If the laser etching isn't very deep, you'll probably need thinner paper. I'm sure you'll find something that works :-)

Comment: You could even use a piece of acetate/clear film wrapped around the cylinder then trace the lettering. Remove the acetate, lay flat, scan, and import into a vector image editor, and use the Bézier tool to redraw the letters, or type letters, reposition, scale/transform as necessary, then delete the raster image after you have finished.

Comment: Dip the cylinder in ink, roll it across a piece of paper, scan the result and trace/redraw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, the dimensions of the cylinder are important for this to work, but one setup that could potentially fix the perspective errors is:

Print on an adhesive material two rulers and paste them on the upper and lower end of the cylinder. Let's say the ruler has 1 mm references.

[image]

Now have vertical printed cardboard for your vertical reference.

[image]

Use the longest focal length you can afford. Let's say a 300mm lens. PUt the camera the further away you can to reduce perspective.

[image]

Now you could use a very slow turntable to rotate it. Make it turn several times so you can align the center of rotation with the center of the cylinder the best you can.

[image]

If you can use an intervalometer, not a video, you have a high-resolution image.

Now you have good reliable references to stitch the segments... probably by hand. Use transparent layers so you can align the segments.

Cross-reference the overall dimensions using some other measuring method, like the thin paper.

---

Probably this is too much tech for the project tho...

Comment: Nope, that's great. Thanks for your input! Going to do this! - Not too technical ;)